# How do we prove that $\max\{x_1 + x_2+ \ldots + x_n - n + 1,0\} \leq C(\textbf{x}) \leq \min\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, copula

I am interested in proving the generalized version of the Fréchet-Hoeffding inequality. Precisely speaking, given a $n$-copula $C:[0,1]^{n}\rightarrow[0,1]$, how do we demonstrate that

$$
\max\{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n - n + 1, 0\} \leq C(\textbf{x}) \leq \min\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}
$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $\textbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \leq (1,1,\ldots,1)$, I have been able to prove the upper bound inequality as next
\begin{align*}
C(\textbf{x}) & \leq C(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1},1)\\
& \leq C(x_1,x_2,\ldots,1,1) \leq \ldots\\
& \leq C(x_1,1,\ldots,1,1) = x_1
\end{align*}
because copulas are non-decreasing in each argument and have uniform margins. Once the same reasoning applies to each coordinate, the result $C(\textbf{x}) \leq \min\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ follows.

But what about the first inequality? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It may not help, but if each $x_i \in [0,1]$ then $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n - n + 1= x_1+(x_2-1)+ \ldots + (x_n-1)$ so $\max\{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n - n + 1, 0\} \le x_1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C(\mathrm x)$ is a cdf of a vector $(U_1,\dots,U_n)$ with $U(0,1)$ marginals. That said, for any $\mathrm x = (x_1,\dots x_n)\in [0,1]^n$, 
$$
C(\mathrm x) = \mathrm{P} (U_1\le x_1,\dots, U_n\le x_n)  = 1 - \mathrm{P} \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{U_i> x_i\}\right)\\
\ge 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{P} (U_i> x_i) = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n (1- x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i - n+ 1.
$$

Comment: In the first place, thanks for the contribution. Could you also provide an answer based on $C$-volumes as well?

Comment: @user1337, I've no idea about $C$-volumes.